# Faster way for removing elements in nested loops

Tags: java

I have a List and a Collection:

```
List<Filter> filters
```

and

```
Collection<Vehicle> vehicles
```

I would like to remove some elements from the first list based on some conditions. But my solution is very slow.
Could you recommend a faster way?
Here is my solution:

```
final Iterator<Filter> iterator = filters.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            final Filter filter = iterator.next();
            for (final Vehicle vehicle : vehicles) {
                if (filter.getX().equalsIgnoreCase(vehicle.getX())
                        && filter.getY().equalsIgnoreCase(vehicle.getY())
                        && filter.getZ().equalsIgnoreCase(vehicle.getZ())) {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: maybe..add a id field that has the composite value of xyz and compare that instead of xyz separate? or use a map to identify the element to be removed separately

Comment: The Java 8 streams' API could be more efficient

Comment: Your approach has time complexity O(MN), it's too bad. 1. Try use a HashMap. You need extra space, but you can do your job in O(N+M). If you restrict extra space usage. Just sort two collection in place, then use 2 pointers, you may have (MlogM) time complexity if your vehicles if linkedList (not arrayList).

Comment: What types are x, y and z for Vehicles? What range of values can each have?

Comment: @Bohemian: x, y and z are strings.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the *time complexity* of your algorithm. With you implementation, for every `Filter` you check the coordinates of every `Vehicle`. If there are `n` filters and `m` vehicles, your code does `n * m` operations. We say this is `O(n * m)` (said as "order n times m").

When the numbers of elements grow, the time taken to complete will quickly blow out.

To make your code faster, you need an `O(n)` algorithm. The best way to do this is the use a `Set` to hold all the vehicle "keys", which is the unique combination of x, y and z.

For clarity, start with a method to build the key:

```
private String key(String x, String y, String z) {
    return String.join("|", x, y, z); // choose separator char not found in values
}
```

Build a Set of keys, then remove filters if their key if found in the set:

```
Set<String> keys = vehicles.stream()
    .map(v -> key(v.getX(), v.getY(), v.getZ())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
filters.removeIf(f -> set.contains(key(f.getX(), f.getY(), f.getZ())));
```

Since each collection is iterated through only once, and the `contains()` method of `HashSet` is `O(1)`, the overall time complexity is now `O(n + m)`, which is as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

When the if test yields `true` and a filter is removed, its fate is sealed, no more story for it, so you can add a `break;` after the line `remove()` so you jump to check next filter right away.

Also, using the inner loop of your code to see if the current filter matches any of the cars takes linear time, and this time will be multiplied by the number of filters, that's a `n*n` complexity(or excution time, to be more straight) in total. Luckily we have a secret weapon called `HashMap`, which can help you look for things in constant time, so by replacing the inner loop with the use of a `HashMap`, we can achieve `n` complexity here, at the cost of building up a `HashMap`, which adds another `n` to our complexity, but still better than `n*n`. You can search for the inner mechanisms of `HashMap`s yourself.

```
final Map<String, Vehicle> map = new HashMap<String, Vehicle>();
for (final Vehicle vehicle : vehicles) {
    //suppose the x,y,z values don't contain '|' character, or this could lead to mistaken removals
    map.put(vehicle.getX()+"|"+vehicle.getY()+"|"+vehicle.getZ(), vehicle);
}
final Iterator<Filter> iterator = filters.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    final Filter filter = iterator.next();
    if(map.containsKey(filter.getX()+"|"+filter.getY()+"|"+filter.getZ())) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Also, the `vehicle`s(which are the `value`s of the `map`) we put in the `map` aren't really used, so we can actually switch to `HashSet` to make our code a bit more elegant(but not much more performance in doing that).

Answer (score 0):

Try this but you have to use java 8 streams

```
 final Set<Filter> collected = vehicles.stream().map(vehicle -> vehicle).
            flatMap(vehicle -> filters.stream().filter(filter -> filter.getX().equalsIgnoreCase(vehicle.getX()) && filter.getY().equalsIgnoreCase(vehicle.getY()) &&
                                    filter.getZ().equalsIgnoreCase(vehicle.getZ())
                    )
            ).
            collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

It's nicely explained in the [ADAM BIEN'S WEBLOG](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/java_8_flatmap_example)

Answer (score 0):

Use **for each** loop instead of Iterator and refactor your code like this

```
    List<Filter> removeFilterList = new ArrayList<Filter>();

    for(Filter filter : filters) {
        for(Vehicle vehicle : vehicles) {
            if(isEqualXYZ(filter, vehicle)) {
                removeFilterList.add(filter);
            }
        }
    }

    filters.removeAll(removeFilterList);

   public boolean isEqualXYZ(Filter filter, Vehicle vehicle) {
        if(filter.getX().equalsIgnoreCase(vehicle.getX())) {//Put your condition here
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Personally I do not recommend Java 8 **stream** over **for each** loop. For each loop is more faster than Java 8 Stream.